# Upload Orchard Project to SVN

Tags: svn, upload, content-management-system, project, orchardcms

I'm new in Orchard
I am building a simple website by Orchard with my friend. I need to upload my project to a SVN server (I'm using Team Foundation Service) so that my friend can get it. Then, I get a trouble that the size of my simple project is so large (about 1.02 Gb) ! I don't know why it is so large while I've just configured some very simple functions.
So, Do you have other solutions to solve that problem ?

Thank you for any helps from all of you !

Comment: Team Foundation Service is its own version control system, it does not use Subversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, consider not source controlling Orchard itself, rather just your modules. If you have an agreed path structure, each of you can check out underneath your local Orchard installation. This worked for us while our project was small.

Here are several specific folders we choose to ignore in git. (ours is an Orchard source code version,  so there may be minor variance). There will be a similar way to exclude in SVN I'm sure.

```
# Orchard Ignores
Orchard.Azure/Orchard.Azure.Web/App_Data
Orchard.Azure/Orchard.Azure.Web/Themes
Orchard.Azure/Orchard.Azure.Web/Modules
Orchard.Web/App_Data
Orchard.Web/Media/Default/RecipeJournal
Orchard.Azure/Orchard.Azure.Web/Modules
Orchard.Azure/Orchard.Azure.Web/Themes
```

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the bin and obj folders, app_data, etc.